# Controlling device with Raspberry PI with different power supply

Tags: power-supply, level-shifting

I want to control USB switch selector with Raspberry PI(RPi).
[image: draft]

The switch ([amazon](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B09KLXRPBQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1)) have an external wired remote with micro button and couple of LEDs.

[image: board]

I need to emulate a button press and ideally read the state of one or both LEDs.
As I think the complication is that RPi and switch are powered from different sources. Looks like I must keep them electrically isolated. I saw the similar question with suggestion to test if grounds are safe to connect with resistor, but my solution must work with different power supplies and I can't test all of them.

I can use relay, optocoupler or transistor based level shifter.
As I understand relays and optocouplers mostly used for high current applications, in my case it is overkill.
Can you recommend some simple solution, ideally that doesn't require complicated assembly? What parameters should I look for?

UPD:

[image: scheme]

Comment: Welcome! Do they share ground?

Comment: I think they don't. Switch is powered by PC's USB and RPi have separate power supply.

Comment: Unless the USB switch provides isolation, then you will ground your RPi via it. Does it have no other wired connection? If no, then it most probably won’t cause any issues.